# CSS for dual divs scrolling independently of each other

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a page with 2 divs, inside a single container div.
I would like to use the left hand side div as a menu, containing various links or text, and to scroll up and down (vertically) by itself.

The second div, shows some content. Usually a table of data, but it could be text too. This div must be able to scroll both horizontally and vertically according to content.

I have some javascript that populates the content for both, but for simplicities sake, I will only show my [css and html](https://jsfiddle.net/s9e3urju/1/):

```
-------------------
|    |            |
| 1  |     2      |
|    |            |
|    |            |
-------------------
```

The issue I have is in IE (I am running IE9), the second div drops off the view, and goes into a second row, instead of being aligned within the the container div. This layout and css works fine in chrome and firefox.

Any ideas on how to make this consistent within IE9?

Comment: The issue is that IE9 doesn't support flexible box layout. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not support `flexbox`, so IE9 is doing what it should, according to its own limited knowledge: it's treating `#browser-view` as a block-level element without a width set, so it's dropping it to the second row.

You'll need to specify a fixed width on `#browser-view` like you did with `#browser-list` and also need to affect its display from its normal `block` default (you could float these divs, make them `display: table-cell`, etc. etc.).

Comment: Maybe I'm pushing my luck here, but would you kindly show me an example by editing my jsFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/s9e3urju/1/

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/s9e3urju/3/. I've removed the flexbox stuff that IE9 can't understand and changed to using a `display: table`/`display: table-cell` approach, which might very well be what you need.

Comment: ah, looks neater, but the 2 divs are not scrolling independently. Thanks for the effort and your clarification on IE9 flex support - I have reverted to a CSS2 solution, as shown in my answer to my own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a bit more research and some testing, I have decided to move away from flexbox in my CSS just so that I can support IE9.

Here is an updated [cross-browser testbed](http://jsfiddle.net/QMsuD/95/), that appears to do what I want and works on all browsers so far.

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}

.Container:before
{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Container:after
{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.Container
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Container > div
{
    height: 100%;
}

.browser-view
{
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: auto;
}

.browser-list
{
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
}
```